# how to deal with JSON that changes?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm sorry for my ignorance since I'm a newbie. I need to check if a twitch stream is live or not. I'm doing this by using `HttpClient` and GET request. The class `TwitchData` deserialize JSON as object is the following.

```
public partial class TwitchData
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pagination")]
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("game_id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long GameId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("community_ids")]
    public object[] CommunityIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("viewer_count")]
    public long ViewerCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("started_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset StartedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thumbnail_url")]
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pagination
{
    [JsonProperty("cursor")]
    public string Cursor { get; set; }
}

public partial class TwitchData
{
    public static TwitchData FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitchData>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this TwitchData self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (long)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
}
```

and I do the request with this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uri = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=59980349";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Client-ID", token);
var result = client.GetStringAsync(uri);
jsonString = result.ToString();
twitchData = PwdResetRequest.FromJson(jsonString);
```

The problem with this is that the JSON changes if the stream is offline thus making the written class `TwitchData` useless to be used for JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.

Following are the JSONs for when the stream is online and offline.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "30356128676",
      "user_id": "59788312",
      "game_id": "498652",
      "community_ids": [],
      "type": "live",
      "title": "A stream",
      "viewer_count": 1325,
      "started_at": "2018-09-07T16:30:09Z",
      "language": "en",
      "thumbnail_url": "url"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "eydBIjpwdWGsLaJhIjp7IkGH4hNl6CH6MXr9"
  }
}
```

and when its offline

```
{
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {}
}
```

Comment: Probably returned JSON data from the server is not standard JSON object.

Comment: making those property nullable and put null check in your converter may help.

Comment: You could try a dynamic deserialization and only access the fields you need each time. There are several stack overflow posts covering the subject.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HOa4dg.   The only problem I could find is that `var twitchData = PwdResetRequest.FromJson(jsonString);` should have been `var twitchData = TwitchData.FromJson(jsonString);`.

Comment: Well also, in `ParseStringConverter`, you should parse using `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`.  But I doubt that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The object I'm creating has 2 variables, `Datum[] data` and `Pagination Pagination`. Frankly, if the stream is offline, only change in JSON string (which can be seen in the question) is that both data array and pagination block is empty. By checking the condition of length of these variables (either checking one of them is enough), I can decide if stream is live or offline. For instance for `getStreams` class,

```
if (getStreams.Datum.Length != 0) {
return true;
}
else {
return false;
}
```